Throwing Exceptions inside a coroutine causes reactor to go on an infinite loop
I have the following code which attempts to process a kafka message, and if it fails, logs/publish it to another topic for later processing.
@Service
class KafkaConsumerService(
    private val kafkaService: KafkaService
) {

    @KafkaListener(topics = ["my-topic"], groupId = "my-group")
    fun listenToTransactionTopic(msg: ConsumerRecord<String, DynamicMessage>, ack: Acknowledgment) = runBlocking {
        val message: ProtoMessage = ProtoMessage.parseFrom(msg.value().toByteArray())

        try {
            kafkaService.process(message)
        } catch(e:Exception){
          // publish to another topic
        }
        finally {
            ack.acknowledge()
        }
    }
}

@Service
class KafkaService(
    private val myentityService: MyEntityService,
    private val kafkaMapper: KafkaMapper.
) {

    companion object {
        private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaService::class.java)
    }

    @Transactional("transactionManager")
    suspend fun process(message: ProtoMessage) {
        val myEntity = myentityService.saveEntity(
            kafkaMapper.map(message)
        )

    // save other var to db by calling other suspend functions

        // produce another message
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            // write a message to a toic
        }
    }

}

class KafkaMapper(
    private val clientService: clientService,
) {
    companion object {
        private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaMapper::class.java)
    }

    suspend fun map(message: ProtoMessage): MyEntity = coroutineScope {

        // expecting a list back
        val remoteCall = clientService.someRemoteCall().awaitSingle() 
    // this uses webApi ==> webClientBuilder.baseUrl(url).filter(oauth2Filter).observationRegistry(observationRegistry).build()

        if (remoteCall.size =! 1) {
            logger.error("Failed :(")
            throw IllegalStateException(error) // this causes inifinte loop if thrown enough times
        }

        return@coroutineScope remoteCall.first()
    }
}

The problem started to arise when I used reactive client to call my other webservices and if I throw any exception from within the mapper function:
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at reactor.core.publisher.InnerOperator.currentContext(InnerOperator.java:33)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.currentContext(MonoFlatMap.java:270)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InnerOperator.currentContext(InnerOperator.java:33)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InnerOperator.currentContext(InnerOperator.java:33)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.currentContext(MonoFlatMap.java:270)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InnerOperator.currentContext(InnerOperator.java:33)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InnerOperator.currentContext(InnerOperator.java:33)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.currentContext(MonoFlatMap.java:270)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InnerOperator.currentContext(InnerOperator.java:33)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InnerOperator.currentContext(InnerOperator.java:33)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.currentContext(MonoFlatMap.java:270)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InnerOperator.currentContext(InnerOperator.java:33)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InnerOperator.currentContext(InnerOperator.java:33)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.currentContext(MonoFlatMap.java:270)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InnerOperator.currentContext(InnerOperator.java:33)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InnerOperator.currentContext(InnerOperator.java:33)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.currentContext(MonoFlatMap.java:270)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InnerOperator.currentContext(InnerOperator.java:33)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InnerOperator.currentContext ... 1000+ lines

What is causing the reactive infinite loop?

Probably not directly related to the problem, but is there a reason you use runBlocking? Usually you should use this only at some entry-point (like the main function) when you don't use a framework that provides a coroutine scope. In all other cases you should create your own coroutine scope and launch a coroutine there.

So if I launch my own scope and launch the coroutine, my consumer starts processing messages from kafka in parallel which for the time being I want to avoid this as I want one consumer per partition. I will be moving to a "reactive" kafka producer/consumer at a later stage

That's no reason to use runBlocking, that's the reason to make listenToTransactionTopic a suspend function.

from what i understand, @kafkalistener annotation does not support reactive functions, thus I either use runblocking or launch through a coroutine scope. assuming I use the launch with coroutine, any way to process one transaction at a time?

The comments are not the right place to discuss this. You can create a new question, though. Please make sure to formulate a specific problem.

Also unrelated, but you will break coroutine functionality by swallowing CancellationExceptions, as you do in that catch block that is catching all Exception types.
